# JavaScript reduce not working on an object

Tags: javascript, reduce

I am trying to understand how reduce works

```js
var expense = [
    {
        item: "Bed",
        cost: 1499,
        date: "02-23-2018"
    },
    {
        item: "Phone",
        cost: 2499,
        date: "02-23-2018"
    },
    {
        item: "Book",
        cost: 400,
        date: "02-23-2018"
    },
    {
        item: "Mattress",
        cost: 700,
        date: "02-23-2018"
    },
    {
        item: "Food",
        cost: 300,
        date: "02-23-2018"
    }
];

var totalExpense = expense.reduce(function (a, b) {
    console.log(a.cost, b.cost);
    return a.cost + b.cost;
});

console.log(totalExpense);
```

this gives totalExpense as `NaN`.

Output:

```
1499 2499
undefined 400
undefined 700
undefined 300
NaN
```

When I perform the same operation with a simple expense array, it works fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first parameter you pass to reduce's callback is the previous value (`a`) - or the second argument you pass to reduce (the initial value)

```
[].reduce(function(a, b) { ... }, 0);
          ^ callback              ^ initial value
```

`a` will hold the result of each previous iteration, So to get the total of all costs, simply add `b.cost`

```js
var expense = [{
    item: 'Bed',
    cost: 1499,
    date: '02-23-2018'
  },
  {
    item: 'Phone',
    cost: 2499,
    date: '02-23-2018'
  },
  {
    item: 'Book',
    cost: 400,
    date: '02-23-2018'
  },
  {
    item: 'Mattress',
    cost: 700,
    date: '02-23-2018'
  },
  {
    item: 'Food',
    cost: 300,
    date: '02-23-2018'
  }
];
var totalExpense = expense.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b.cost;
}, 0);

console.log(totalExpense);
```

Using es6 syntax you could make it a one liner

```
var totalExpense = expense.reduce((a, {cost}) => a + cost, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an initial value which has a `cost` field in order to reference it in the accumulator.  And you need to return that object:

```
expense.reduce(function(acc, curr){
    console.log(acc.cost, curr.cost);
    acc.cost += curr.cost;
    return acc;
    }, { cost: 0 });
```

Note the use of more meaningful variable names than `a` and `b`.  This will make your code easier to understand.  The `Array.prototype.reduce` callback should have an accumulator and current value.  Name them as such to help yourself.  The initial value provides an object with a `cost` field where you can write down your accumulated value.

Note that you could also just use a vanilla variable here if you wanted to.   If you don't actually need an object:

```
var total = expense.reduce(function(acc, curr){
    acc += curr.cost;
    return acc;
    }, 0);
 console.log(total);
 >> 5398
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` whatever the next `a` should be. `a.cost + b.cost` is a number. It doesn’t have a `cost` property, so `a.cost` will be `undefined` after the first iteration.

Just provide a starting value `0`. Also consider giving your parameters more appropriate names.

```
var totalExpense = expense.reduce(function(sum, item){
  return sum + item.cost;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an initial value. The reduce function takes the accumulated value as first parameter and the next element of the collection as second

```
var totalExpense = expense.reduce(function(accumulator, current) {
console.log({ accumulator: accumulator, currentCost: current.cost });
return accumulator + current.cost;
}, 0);

console.log({ totalExpense: totalExpense });
```

Answer (score 0):

//total cost by reduce method

let totalExpense = expense.reduce((tem,val) => tem+=val.cost,0)
console.log(totalExpense)

Answer (score -1):

```js
expense.reduce((sum, cur) => ({ cost: sum.cost + cur.cost })).cost;
```

---

**Updated**
As @Viktor pointed, I didn't consider special case before.

```
function getTotelExpense(expense) {
    if (expense.length > 0 && expense[0].hasOwnProperty("cost"))
        return expense.reduce((sum, cur) => ({ cost: sum.cost + cur.cost })).cost;
    else return 0;
}
```

You can learn more in [TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Reduce_of_empty_array_with_no_initial_value)

Comment: This reduce will return `undefined` for empty lists.
`.cost` of `undefined` will crash. Actually I'm wrong. Running the code you get instant `TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value`

Comment: @Viktor Thank you. I didn't consider empty cases.

Answer (score -2):

Here's another way you can do it using the generic function `foldMap` – for more guidance on this beautiful function, I recommend [this video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-unboxing-things-with-foldable).

```
const totalExpense =
  expense.foldMap (item => item.cost, 0)

console.log (totalExpense)
// 5398
```

For this, you'll need to define `Array.prototype.foldMap` and `Number.prototype.concat` – but this implementation and where it is defined is up to you

```
Array.prototype.foldMap = function (f, acc)
{
  return this.reduce ((acc, x, i) =>
    acc.concat (f (x, i, this)), acc)
}

Number.prototype.concat = function (m)
{
  return this + m
}
```

Here's a functioning code paste

```js
Array.prototype.foldMap = function (f, acc)
{
  return this.reduce ((acc, x, i) =>
    acc.concat (f (x, i, this)), acc)
}

Number.prototype.concat = function (m)
{
  return this + m
}

const expense =
  [ { item: 'Bed'
    , cost: 1499
    , date: '02-23-2018'
    }
  , { item: 'Phone'
    , cost: 2499
    , date: '02-23-2018'
    }
  , { item: 'Book'
    , cost: 400
    , date: '02-23-2018'
    }
  , { item: 'Mattress'
    , cost: 700
    , date: '02-23-2018'
    }
  , { item: 'Food'
    , cost: 300
    , date: '02-23-2018'
    }
  ]
  
const totalExpense =
  expense.foldMap (item => item.cost, 0)

console.log(totalExpense)
// 5398
```